# C overriding C++ method

Tags: c++, c, polymorphism

### expr.hpp

```
typedef int (*evaluate)(PExp);
typedef void (*printTo)(PExp, FILE *);
typedef void (*Exp_free)(PExp);

class Expression {
public:
     virtual int  evaluate()          abstract; 
     virtual void printTo(FILE * out) abstract;  
     virtual void free();                       
};

class Value : public Expression {
protected:
    int value;
    Value(int value);
public:
    int evaluate();
};
```

---

### Expression.h

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

typedef struct expression Expression;
typedef Expression * PExp;

typedef int (*evaluate)(PExp);
typedef void (*printTo)(PExp, FILE *);
typedef void (*Exp_free)(PExp);

typedef struct {
    evaluate exp_evaluate;
    printTo exp_printTo;
    Exp_free exp_free;
} vTable;

struct expression {
    vTable * v;
};

void expression_init(PExp this);
void exp_free(PExp this);
```

---

### Value.h

```
#include "Expression.h"

typedef struct {
    Expression super;
    int value;
} Value;

void value_init(Value * this, int value);
int value_evaluate(Value * this);
```

---

### Constant.h

```
typedef struct {
    Value super;
} Constant;

void constant_init(Constant * this, int value);
void constant_free(Constant * this);
void constant_printTo(Constant * this, FILE * out);
```

---

### expr.h

```
#include "Expression.h"
#include "Value.h"
#include "Constant.h"
```

---

### main.c

```
#include "expr.h"

void constant_init(Constant * this, int value) {
    _ZN5ValueC2Ei((Value *)this, value);
    printf("%d\n", this->super.super.v->exp_evaluate((PExp)this));
    this->super.super.v->exp_printTo = (printTo)constant_printTo; // MARK
}

void constant_printTo(Constant * this, FILE * out) {
    fprintf(out, "%d", this->super.value );
    putchar('\n');
}
```

---

I'm currently trying to implement some code which constructs some objects in C while using C++ at the same time. The classes "Expression" and "Value" are given in C++ and I have to implement the class "Constant" which extends "Value" in C. I cannot change anything in the C++ files (including new files) so that's why I call the "Value" constructor by it's mangled name. The question is: I can call the method exp_evaluate which is defined in the class "Value" but when I try to override the method exp_printTo (MARKED line) it always gives me Segmentation Fault, so what am I doing wrong here?. If I try to call the method, instead of trying to assign another value to the function pointer, it terminates as expected because it is a pure virtual method. Here is the makefile showing that "main" is compiled with 3 C++ files and main.c:

```
main: use-expr.o expr.o main.o
    g++ -o use-expr-c use-expr.o expr.o main.o -g

use-expr.o: use-expr.cpp expr.hpp
    g++ -Wall -pedantic -g -c use-expr.cpp -g

expr.o: expr.cpp expr.hpp
    g++ -Wall -pedantic -g -c expr.cpp -g

main.o: main.c
    gcc -Wall -pedantic -std=c99 -g -c -o main.o main.c -g
```

It all compiles, the only error I get is at runtime.
I hope there's enough information.
Thank you in advance.

Comment: Can't say I've read all the post, but it doesn't look like you're handling calling conventions difference (`__thiscall` vs `__cdecl`).

Comment: Oh, and one can't change vtable contents, it's in read-only memory

Comment: So I can't change the methods 1 by 1, but I have to create a separate table and then change the vTable pointer, is that it?

Comment: Yes, but it's suboptimal, if you will create separate vtable for every instance.

Comment: If it's not mangled in the way that breaks `C` syntax, you can copy vtable once when the application starts. Or use some hack -)

Comment: Thanks, im working on it. But how is it polymorphism supposed to work? If it is not possible to change only 1 method and creating a different vTable for each instance is suboptimal what is the best way? Thanks a lot by the way.

Comment: Either copy it the way I mentioned above, or copy it once in constructor wrapper during construction of the first instance, and save its address to static variable, I suppose

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd suggest you implement a small wrapper (in C++) that calls the C++, and make the function there have C linkage using `extern C`. This is a far more reliable method than calling mangled C++ names.

If you really want to know what's up, I'm afraid it's time to break out `gdb`.

Comment: i appreciate your comment but I cannot change anything in C++, including new files :\ I have been using gbd and that's how I managed to pinpoint the error. It got to a point where I simply do not understand why.

Comment: In your question you say "I cannot change anything in the C++ files so that's why I call the "Value" constructor by it's mangled name". It might be useful to clarify you can't add a separate C++ file either, though I'd be interested to know why on earth not! You might try using a separate C++ file and disassembling it to see how it differs from your route (if you need a 'final answer' in C, as opposed to have mysteriously deleted your `g++` binary).

Comment: The reason I cant change or add C++ files is because it is asked (well, demanded) not to. I understand the easiest way would be to create a wrapper but since I cannot do it I think it's better to understand why can't I change a function pointer. Thanks for the answer btw.

Comment: So my second idea was to temporarily use the wrapper to understand where the C method went wrong, then fix your C method.

Comment: The method constant_printTo is well implemented. I can call it separately with no error. The error only occurs when I try to assign a value to the function pointer in this->super.super.v->exp_prinTo(Expression.vTable->exp_printTo).

Comment: @DiogoFerreira: just curious what reasons would someone have to not let you modify the c++ code?

Comment: @DiogoFerreira: hang on a sec. Aren't you trying to write to a vtable here? I thought vtables were read only and in the code segment. This would explain the seg fault.

Comment: Yea that was the problem, I was not aware of that and now I'm using malloc for the vTables which does not feel right but it works :\